# Way to join two sentences

Tags: passive-voice, relative-pronouns, active-voice, run-on-sentences

> 1. Even though, the line segments are rectified by the orientation,
>      awkward short edges are still appeared.
> 2. Therefore, a simplification step is important.

What is the rule to join these two sentences as I want to reduce my word count?

Here is my effort

> Even though, the line segments are rectified by the orientation,
>   awkward short edges are still appeared *in which* a simplification step
>   is important.

Can I use a "clause" for this case?

Comment: Ya gotta start by getting the first sentence right. No comma after "even though", "awkward", and "edges still appear".

Comment: "Orientation rectifies the line segments, but awkward short edges call for a simplification step."

Comment: @StoneyB - why don't you post your answer as an answer, rather than a comment?

Comment: @fred2 Cause I'm at work now and haven't got time to explain why it's better. Take it and run with it if you like!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@StoneyB's suggestion is a good, concise solution.

> "Orientation rectifies the line segments, but awkward short edges call
>   for a simplification step."

It does a number of things:

1. Changes passive voice to active. Active voice tends to be shorter, as it replaces 'are rectified by' with 'rectify'.
2. 'but awkward short edges' replaced 'awkward short edges still appeared'. The appearance of edges is implied by the sentence, and does not necessarily have to be stated. If you felt the need for some additional clarification, you could write it as "but the appearance of awkward short edges calls for ..."
3. Three cumbersome clauses replaced with two.

Comment: + 1. Makes it look like I did it on purpose!